# including a template within another template in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a very simple wordpress project. One of the page will have thumbnails of my projects and some texts and when I will click on the thumbnails it will land me to the page corresponding to the project. I created a template where i am trying to include another template which will just hold the thumbnails. I want to be able to update the thumbnails and text from two different pages from the wordpress dashboard. This is what I have so far...the concept is kinda goofy...let me know if i explained it correctly

lets say this is the rendering template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: projects
* This template displays project thumbnails and introductory copy as a rendering template
*/
$options = twentyeleven_get_theme_options();
$current_layout = $options['theme_layout'];
get_header();?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                    <? /*php comments_template( '', true ); */?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'projectThumb', 'true' ); ?>
            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and this is the thumbnail template.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: projectThumb
* This template displays project thumbnails at the project page
*/
$options = twentyeleven_get_theme_options();
$current_layout = $options['theme_layout'];
get_header();?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: why do need a template inside a template, why not instead create a gallery and render image page instead?

Comment: so basically there would be one template for the thumbnail gallery which will hold the text too? is that what you are saying?

Comment: yeah have your one template on a page called gallery and then another template on a page called "render" for lack of a better word